# grails createcriteria filtering with enum type

Tags: grails, enums, hibernate-criteria

```
def employee = Person.createCriteria().listDistinct {
    eq "personType" UserType.EMPLOYEE
    or {
        ilike "name", "%" + params.searchValue + "%"
        ilike "lastName", "%" + params.searchValue + "%"
    }
}
```

I want to do this query by filtering persons who are only employees.

> The domain is Person
>
> The enum is personType

The problem is that personType is an enum.
I'm getting this error

```
No signature of method: myController.eq() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [personType] Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), grep(), raw(java.lang.Object), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

I also tried `eq "personType" "EMPLOYEE"` and `eq "personType" PersonType.valueOf(PersonType.EMPLOYEE)`

Thanks

Comment: Can you include in your post your domain and your enum as well?

Comment: done, the domain is Person and the enum is PersonType

Comment: I meant can you post the code for both. I know they are a domain class and an enum. I was asking if you could include the source for both so you posted a question with all the details needed to answer your specific question.

Comment: `,` missing in `eq "personType" UserType.EMPLOYEE`. should be `eq "personType", UserType.EMPLOYEE`

Comment: wow, my bad that was it :/. I'll just delete this question.don't tell anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
eq "personType" UserType.EMPLOYEE.name()
```

Or If your enumType is ordinal:

```
eq "personType" UserType.EMPLOYEE.ordinal()
```